# Bottom border on matplotlib bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I'm trying to make a bar plot in using matplotlib, without the "box" or axis ticks, as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar([1, 2], [150, 250], edgecolor = 'black', linewidth = 1, \
       color = '#EEFFCC')

ax.set_xticks([1, 2])
plt.tick_params(bottom = False, left = False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
```

Particularly, I don't want the "box" but I want the bars to have a black border. However, when I make the plot, it looks like this:

[image]

And the bottom border isn't there (ostensibly since I got rid of the bottom "box" spine). If I try to set linewidth = 2 or higher, the border is there but is a lot thinner than the top, left, or right borders.

Is there anyway that I can have the bottom border display at the same length as the top/left/right borders for the bar? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If lines (or anything else) go beyond the figure extent in matplotlib they are clipped (which is happening to your boxes). If you force then to not be clipped then it will work.

Changing the relevant line:

```
ax.bar([1, 2], [150, 250], edgecolor = 'black', linewidth = 1, \
       color = '#EEFFCC', clip_on=False)
```

Gives:
[image]